# Not able exit from docker container with bash script containing exit command

Tags: bash, docker

I'm able to exit when I enter the `exit` command in container environment. But if I try to run a script file having the `exit` command, I'm not able to exit from the container.

1.working

```
ubuntu@iot-docker:/repo$ exit
exit
 
root@iot-docker:/repo# exit
exit

ubuntu@ubuntu-***-Twr:~/shirisha/plo-***-snt-sp_u103a3$
```

---

2. not working

```
script.sh
   
#!/bin/bash
exit
   
exit
```

Comment: What are you actually expecting it to do? `exit` exits the script.

Comment: expecting to exit from container by executing 'script.sh'

Comment: ubuntu@iot-docker:/repo$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
exit
exit
ubuntu@iot-docker:/repo$ ./script.sh
ubuntu@iot-docker:/repo$
ubuntu@iot-docker:/repo$

Comment: expecting - ubuntu@ubuntu--Twr:~/shirisha/plo--snt-sp_u103a3$

Comment: How are you calling script.sh? From a compose file? From a `docker exec` command? Directly via the commandline inside the container?

Comment: The default behavior of a Docker container is to stop after the last process in it is running. If bash is not the last process that is running inside the container, then the container will still be running/up.

Comment: directly via the commandline inside the container

Comment: Then I would suggest @xhienne's answer.

Comment: Thank you! @xdhmoore

Answer (score 1):

`exit` is not a command to exit your container, it just exits the current shell interpreter.

When you run your script, a new shell interpreter is started according to the first line of your script (here `/bin/bash`). When it encounters the `exit` command, the interpreter stops and you get back to the command line (the previous shell).

You can make this expriment:

```
$ bash     # Starts a new shell
$ exit     # Exits the new shell; we come back to the old one
exit
$
```

See? Running `bash` in command line is similar to running your script, and exiting from it brings you back to your previous shell. You didn't exit your container.

Solution:

```
exec script.sh param1 ... paramN
```

`exec` will replace your current shell with the command being started (`script.sh`). When that command exits, you will exit your container because your old shell no longer exists.

Comment: Thank you! @xhienne

Comment: i had to run 'exec script.sh ' twice to exit container. Is there any way i could run it once?

Comment: I do not understand how it is possible, especially since in your question only one manual exit is necessary. If you must run it twice, then that means you have a shell interpreter that has run another shell interpreter. You didn't call `bash` like in my experiment, did you? (that was just an experiment)

Comment: for launching docker, used yocto_build.sh file(it has docker run command). Trying to exit from docker container instead entering 'exit' command twice to exit from container, added exit command twice in script.sh.and tried executing it.

Comment: @shirisha If I understand you correctly, you have to enter `exit` twice manually (on the command line) to exit your shell? Is it what is shown in your question? In your question, one exit seems to exit a `su` or `sudo` shell for an unprivileged user (`$` prompt). The second one is used to exit the primary shell for root (`#` prompt). If your question is correct, you seem to have something that executes a non-privileged shell. I can hardly help further as this is tied to your installation.

Answer (score 0):

When you script a script without "sourcing" the script, the script will be started in a new subprocess. The `exit` works, you will finish that subprocess.
It is important to remember, that a script starts a new environment.

Look at the script example.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
my_value=high
cd /tmp
```

Call this script with

```
cd $HOME
my_value="low"
./example.sh
pwd
echo "My value is now ${my_value}"
```

Now nothing has changed: all changes in the subprocess are gone.
You can call this script with `source ./example.sh` (or short `. ./example.sh`),
and things have changed.

When you don't want to source your script, a function (in `.bashrc`) might help:

```
example() {
   my_value=high
   cd /tmp
}
```

Now you can call the function:

```
cd $HOME
my_value="low"
example
pwd
echo "My value is now ${my_value}"
```